# Sublime Text 2 plugin to sort your functions alphabetically

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, package-control

I am building many functions in my application and now I want to alphabetise them. Is there any function in Sublime Text 2 that will do this automatiaclly. It should change these

```
public function login_1()
{
........
}

public function about()
{
........
}

public function close()
{
........
}
```

Into these

```
public function about()
{
........
}

public function close()
{
........
}

public function login_1()
{
........
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you are using PHP, from the syntax you provided it seems you do.

[Here is a plugin](https://github.com/foxxyz/sublime_alphpetize) for that task, but it looks like it works with PHP only. It sorts your methods using the scope first and then by method name.